# Bootstrap Badges are Overlapping

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue where bootstrap's badges, which I use as tags in my project are overlapping eachother if they wrap to the next line. It looks like [image: this] I use almost the exact same method(s) to display those tags on a separate page, but for some reason, they are only broken in this case.

Comment: Could you post your actual code please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add styles (i.e. padding-top and padding-bottom) to the badges in your CSS.

```
<span class="badge", style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Custom Map</span>
```